# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects

Tags: css, less, saas

When I run less (version 2.5) in chrome it throws an error:

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

After some research I figured that the reason is because by default `async` been set as `false`. less.org docs show the below under the Async category.

**CodeGiven:**

```
<script>
  less = {
    env: "development",
    logLevel: 2,
    async: false, //default is false
    fileAsync: false,
    poll: 1000,
    functions: {},
    dumpLineNumbers: "comments",
    relativeUrls: false,
    globalVars: {
      var1: '"string value"',
      var2: 'regular value'
    },
    rootpath: ":/a.com/"
  };
</script>
```

Since my requirement is to set `async` to `true` I added the below code just before loading less.js and the error seems to be gone.

**CodeUsed:**

```
   <script>
     less = {
       async: true
     };
   </script>
```

My question: Is it okay to do this (CodeUsed) or do I have to use the full code (CodeGiven) as per less.org docs? The reason for asking is because I read that setting `async = true` is terrible for developing?

Comment: see also https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2384. Yes `async: true` should remove the warning. Does the warning hinder you when developing? In most cases you should not use less in browser for production. For development i should use the settings which best fits your need. CodeGiven is only an example

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. Leave `async = true`.

As the warning says, it is not a good idea to run it on the main thread because of the possibility of a bad user experience. Most users don't like it when the browser freezes. You especially don't want your site to freeze when your server goes down or is running slow, as you will get a bad user experience.

Running your requests asynchronously is simply a better and more manageable solution.

Comment: No. I'm saying that you should leave `async = true` for all the reasons I stated.

Comment: what about for situations where you have to ensure the content is loaded before you can do something with it? In those situations will async=false still work in the future? (For example, lets say you pull in a script that has variables that you need before you can move forward correctly).